# Joomla PHP using a text file to blacklist words

Tags: php, file, joomla, strpos

So i have a text document in my joomla root path called `banned.txt` contents look like the following (on new lines):

```
fuck
fucking
etc
```

Now the way i have already solved this is with the following code. But rather than have a big list of arrays in my php code i would rather just somehow pull the banned words from the text document in my `public_html` folder.

```
$mtitle = $file['name'];
$find = array('fuck', 'fucking', 'etc');
foreach ($find as $n) {
    if(strpos($mtitle,$n) !== false) {
        $this->setError(JText::_('Banned word detected'));
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any help in order to pull out `c:/website/public_html/banned.txt` and check that file to see if any of the words match would be great :)

Comment: Joomla has bad word handling in com_contact, just copy the code from there.

Comment: Have a look at ReReplacer

Comment: @johnny_s rereplace is a extension this a custom built component i need PHP code not a exsisting extension my needs are different. Also elin do you know the line numbers or specific files i should be looking in to save my searching through the entire component.

Comment: @Elin do you know the line numbers or specific files i should be looking in to save my searching through the entire component.

Comment: Look here https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/staging/components/com_contact/models/rules  those are three separate rules for filtering specific terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't `file` be suitable for your purposes? As we can read in [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

> **file** — Reads entire file into an array

So using `file` your code would look like this:

```
$mtitle = $file['name'];
$find = file("c:/website/public_html/banned.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($find as $n) {
    if(strpos($mtitle,$n) !== false) {
        $this->setError(JText::_('Banned word detected'));
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please note, that only line with defining `$find` has changed, as `file` is returning array.

**EDIT:**

It appears that `file` is splitting file with newlines still attached. To ignore them you must use **`FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`** as second parameter. I've updated code to contain it.

> Each line in the resulting array will include the line ending, unless
>   FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES is used, so you still need to use rtrim() if you
>   do not want the line ending present.

Comment: Thanks I did that but when i put a word on a new line in banned.txt and i save or upload a file it does not detect the word. How can i fix this. It does detect it if there is only one word in the file, but i need multiple words in the file. :(

Comment: And i seperate each word on a new line.

Comment: I'll make some tests with your code and i'll get back to you.

Comment: Found it. It's all about `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` parameter. I've updated my answer.

Comment: So compared to my soloution would you know what is better to use ? $find = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents("c:/website/public_html/banned.txt"));

Comment: Please keep in mind, that saving text files differs on different operating systems. Lines will not always be delimited with `\r\n` - sometimes it could be only `\r` or `\n`. Also `file` has some additional params like `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` which does what it sounds like :) Read more about it on [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Answer (score 2):

Com_contact contains three rules for filtering specific strings (emails, subject line and message) an you can find them here https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/staging/components/com_contact/models/rules.

What you should do in your component (assuming you don't just want to count on loading those rules) is create your own rule and put it in the same location in your file hierarchy. Look at com_contact to see how to make he words configurable and also how to add it to the form definition.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the following seems to have worked for me with a Windows OS. In banned.txt i have seperated each banned word by a new line.

Banned.txt :

```
fuck
fucking
etc
```

PHP :

```
$mtitle = $file['name'];
//$find = array('fuck', 'fucking', 'etc');
$find = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents("c:/website/public_html/banned.txt"));
foreach ($find as $n) {
    if(strpos($mtitle,$n) !== false) {
        $this->setError(JText::_('Banned word detected'));
        return false;
    }
}
```

If anyone has any improvements or sees any problems with me using this code please do say so help on improvements is appreciated.